# Use MatDatePicker under reactive form in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to use matdatepicker input type as a property of reactive form in angular. I have **organizationValue** as formcontrol in reactive form group.

This is how I am using it in html

```
<input class="inbox-width" matInput formControlName="organizationValue" [matDatepicker]="organizationValue">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="organizationValue"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #organizationValue></mat-datepicker>
```

You can see that I have added name **organizationValue** in attribute **formControlName**.

When I try to output all the values of form (after filling) in typescript file using command:

```
this.formData.value
```

organizationValue attribute show **null** but other simple input types in the form like textbox, radio, checkbox show correct values.

What can be the reason that the reactive form property is not bind to matdatepicker?

Using it as nested reactive form as shown:

```
<form *ngIf="companies" [formGroup]="editForm">
  <div formArrayName="organizations" *ngFor="let organization of editForm.controls.organizations.controls; let i = index;">
    <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
      <div class="row row-margin">
        <label class="col-sm-3">{{organization.get('organizationTitle').value}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input class="inbox-width" matInput formControlName="organizationValue" [matDatepicker]="organizationValue" [ngClass]="organization.get('organizationBorderError').value"
            (dateInput)="orgValueChange(i)">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="organizationValue"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #organizationValue></mat-datepicker>
        </div>
      ...
```

Comment: ı have it in nested form am not able to get the values from the main form